# 18.04.1 Software Updater erratic in choosing nearest mirror

Tags: updates

When trying to obtain a close software updater mirror in Canada, system will show mirror(s) in Vietnam, U.S.A, or any other place other than Canada.

Consequently I have to choose a mirror manually.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you go to settings -> privacy, is location services turned on?

Answer (score 1):

From the manual:

> Use mirror protocol
>
> Using mirror protocol as part of your
>   `/etc/apt/sources.list`  entry will instruct apt command to fetch mirrors
>   located within your country only. In order to use mirror protocol
>   update all lines within `/etc/apt/sources.list` file from the usual eg.:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
```

> to:

```
 deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial main restricted
```

> Repeat the above for all relevant lines where appropriate.
>
> Alternatively, use sed command to automatically edit your
>   `/etc/apt/sources.list file`. Update the below sed command where
>   appropriate to fit your environment:

```
$ sudo sed -i -e 's/http:\/\/us.archive/mirror:\/\/mirrors/' -e 's/\/ubuntu\//\/mirrors.txt/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Seems to work, after a bit of "tinkering" on my part.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Demas no problem. I would myself always opt for "fastest mirror"  though. (that is probably what you see happening: the Canada mirror is slower than the one from Thailand, or the US).